# How can use :grep with range in neovim with ripgrep as external grep program?

Tags: neovim, search, grep, ripgrep

I am using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) as external grep program in neovim. Which works when I call `:grep 'pattern'` in neovim Command Mode.

I frequently have to search some strings within a blocked range in long json files (i do not want to search the entire file but only within a range).

I would love to know,

1. If it is possible to use vim `:grep` with range ?
2. How can I use `:grep 'pattern' %` to search with a visually selected range only in the given file and not the entire file ?

I tried `15,82grep '^\s{8}\w+' %` but it does not respect the range provided and searches the pattern with in the entire files !!

Comment: `:grep` does not work with range. It calls an external program and parses the output into the quickfix list. If I'm not mistaken, you want to pipe the visually-selected text to ripgrep and put the results in the qflist, right? That can be achieved by a custom function. But not by the standard `:h :grep` and `:h gp` system.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/xosfpb/how_can_use_grep_with_range_in_neovim_with/

Answer (score 1):

Vim/Neovim internal `:vimgrep` works for me.

```
:vimgrep /^\%V\s\{8}\a\+/ %
```

All results are places in quickfix list, grep search results respects the given visual range provided.

Cheers